# Can I round robin connections in connection pool to different reader instances with hikariCP/hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, mysql-connector, hikaricp

Most examples of multiple database for hikariCP are different databases like mySQL, postgres.  We are finding a strange connection load on mySQL readers where 1 reader has most of the connections.  As we are also moving to auto-scaling, we want a connection pool that for each connection, randomly chooses one of the 3 reader jdbc URL's locking that connection to that reader instance.  Is this possible with HikariCP and hibernate at all?  I have been searching for an example on how to do that perhaps each call to some getConnection somewhere to use 1 of 3 jdbc urls so each connection is to different reader.

Also, as a bonus, I wonder if I can check the count of all connections to instance 1, 2, 3 and always choose the instance with the lowest connection count (from my server's perspective not from the database perspective since I don't expect to query mysql for active connections though that could be interesting too to better balance things as well - I am not sure if that is possible).

Read many articles but they are mostly around postgres&mysql or oracle&mysql rather than ONE database with many reader instances.

Comment: please share how you connect to DB and a bit of detail about infra (do you run on AWS RDS by any chance?)

Comment: previous company on GCP, this one on RDS but that is not too relevant as I want to do it in all environments.  this is a more general question on if I have 1 writer db url, and 4 reader urls, can I perhaps have the 4 reader urls such that the connection pool contains 5 for url1, 5 for url2, etc. etc to typically 20 connections in the pool @fedden

Comment: I am also going to ask here -> https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/2077 since got no traction on this question.

Comment: This is a driver concern not the concern of a connection pool. I believe the mysql drier has this build in with a special JDBC url.